# Update exp-Cli in react-native

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I want to update my expo CLI. When I run this npm install -g expo-cli or npm i -g expo-cli@latest command so I got following errors in my console.

[image: console]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please don't put code or any text as an image when a copy/paste is possible and also allows ops to proceed. Did you take some time to review the [tour] and [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing npm cache by command `npm cache clean --force` and then re-run the command `npm install -g expo-cli`